# Implementar el modo nocturno en Android

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Tengo entendido que Android hay un modo nocturno es decir que diferencia si es de día o de noche, mi pregunta es ¿Cómo obtener ese dato y así poder cambiar de un tema claro a un tema oscuro?

**Update**

El problema que me surge después de encontrar como implementar el tema de dia/noche es que cuando rota el dispositivo no acaba de tener el mismo aspecto.

Comment: He encontrado algo sobre eso http://android-developers.blogspot.com.es/2016/02/android-support-library-232.html

Comment: Un helper para detectar el modo si está activado o no https://gist.github.com/slightfoot/c508cdc8828a478572e0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mirando la [documentación oficial](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/UiModeManager.html) se puede obtener de `UiModeManager`.

También he encontrado ese [tutorial](http://blog.nkdroidsolutions.com/android-daynight-theme-example-using-appcompat-v23-2/) que lo implementa de una forma simple.

Resumiendo:
Android el modo Dia Noche, se puede diferenciar con el sufijo `-night` y en la definición del tema `Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.DarkActionBar` los colores de la interfaz nocturna estarán en `values-night/colors.xml`

Para establecer de forma que lo detecte automáticamente

```
AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_AUTO);
```

Si se quiere forzar que se vea en modo Noche

```
AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES);
```

Si se quiere ver en la manera por defecto es decir modo dia.

```
AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);
```

Ejemplo descargable del tutorial: [DayNightThemeExample](https://github.com/niravkalola/DayNightThemeExample)